# How to make sql server database setup

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have an application that uses SQL Server Express.  How to make setup that will install the application on client's computer?

I searched a lot on google but nothing found helpful.

Also tried this link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Deploy_your_database.aspx

but got stuck on step 3.  Please help.

Thanks

Comment: need to know the exact problem you're having on step 3.  Are you looking for the setup in Visual Studio or Sql Server Management Studio?  Are you getting an error message?

Comment: I donot know how to add installer class and overide it (as mentioned in the article)  Also how to add the code given in vb.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this article : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264562(v=sql.90).aspx#emsqlexcustapp_topic3